# Is there a point where the electric field strength is zero for two point charges of opposite signs put together?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, singularities, coulombs-law

I searched online that there is no 'neutral point' in the electric field of two charges of opposite signs, unlike the electric field of two positive charges.

However my question is when you put 2 charges of opposite signs on the x axis, is there a point where the E strength is equal to zero?

The two charges carry the same magnitude of charge but different signs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.